# Como somar apenas os maiores valores de uma sequencia numérica no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quero somar apenas os valores maiores que '600' dessa sequencia numérica, tentei utilizar o =SOMASE(B51:B60;>600;B51:B60), mas não deu certo! logo depois de inserir o simbolo do (>)maior, ele anula o restante da fórmula, como eu faço para somar apenas os valores maiores que '600' ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica está quase certa, só teve um pequeno erro na hora de implementar, veja o exemplo:

```
=SOMASE(rage; ">1000")
```

**Exemplo:**

```
=SOMASE(B51:B60; ">1000")
```

Aonde `range` é aonde quer somar, e o `">10"` é o parâmetro de exclusão.

Referencia:
https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-greater-than

Answer (score 2):

Outra maneira de fazer a fórmula, além do que o @Bulfaitelo mencionou, é adicionar um "&" entre o sinal de comparação e a área de valores.

Exemplo:

```
=SOMASE(B51:B60; ">" & 600)
```

Com isso você consegue referenciar o valor do critério para um intervalo.

Exemplo de uma soma dos valores maiores que a média do mesmo intervalo:

```
=SOMASE( B51:B60; ">" & MÉDIA( B51:B60 ) )
```